# Find number of rows in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to find the number of rows in a table from C#.

Please give me some guide.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean by "length"... number of rows, data size, data + index size, maximum row size, ...?

Comment: I want to get number of rows.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;`

Comment: @Muhammad - Exactly or quick and dirty way?

Comment: Better **HOW**?? `SELECT COUNT(*)` will get you the **exact number** but it might take a long time to calculate, while inspecting the metadata gives you a quick answer, but it might be inaccurate. So which is **better** to you???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Length FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 4):

This will not necessarily be accurate due to transactions that may be in flight (the same issue that can occur if you use less aggressive isolation levels / NOLOCK).

```
  SELECT [RowCount] = SUM(row_count)
      FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.tablename')
      AND index_id IN (0,1);
```

This will be much faster than `SELECT COUNT(*)` but it depends on your goal - do you want 100% accuracy at the cost of concurrency, or do you want a ballpark?

Comment: Accuracy is better so I'll stick to "select count(*)" :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well on a busy system it's always going to be a moving target. If it takes 20 seconds to get the result using `COUNT(*)`, it'll likely be incorrect by the time you display it anyway...

Comment: This also includes the count of forwarding pointers on a heap and (really pedantic one coming up) can be manually set e.g. with `create table dbo.tablename (x int);update statistics dbo.tablename with rowcount = 1000000`

Comment: @Martin Heaps!? Weren't those deprecated!?!?

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of rows, you can simply use the COUNT function:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) Length 
FROM    SomeTable
```

Comment: Your first line is incorrect. `COUNT(*)` = `COUNT(1)` = `COUNT(1/0)` = `COUNT(Any_Non_Nullable_Column)`

Comment: Can you elaborate? My comment or my SELECT?

Comment: I Elaborated my original comment RE: Your comment.

Comment: Thanks, it's been updated. Why then is `SELECT *` so discouraged? I've always heard that it's better to explicitly declare columns rather than using `*`. Is it's application in the `COUNT` function different from `SELECT *`?

Comment: `SELECT *` <> `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: Good to know... that's interesting.

Comment: `SELECT *` returns every row in the table, whether you're going to use them or not. `SELECT COUNT(*)` tells the DB to decide what the most efficient way is to determine the number of rows and return a single column containing that row count.

Comment: @Ken White: I figured as much, but thought that the "decision making" process could yield worse performance. Consider me enlightened.

Comment: A note on Select * and Select (LIST OF COLUMNS):
For Select * , SQL Server polls the table of tables for all the column names for the listed table, then fills in the columns, and executes the query. For improved performance, just use Select <every single column listed out.> Similarly Select Count(*) requires SQL to do some thinking for you to fill in the rest of the query, you can expect better performance by choosing a column with non-null values like Select(ID). Select Count(1) is very fast, but counts the row regardless of null values...

Comment: @EtherDragon (1) performance is the *least* important reason to avoid SELECT * and list out all the columns instead. Can you provide a repro that shows a tangible performance difference? (2) `COUNT(*)` ***does NOT*** expand the column list in any way whatsoever. And the only reason you'd ever use COUNT(column) is if you *wanted* a count of only the rows where that column was not NULL - not a very common requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the obvious way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable;
```

I'll let Aaron or someone else post the *fast* way to do it, then we'll have the accuracy discussion/clarification...  :-D

Comment: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM yourTable, or SELECT COUNT(SomeIndexedIDColumn) FROM yourTable

Comment: SELECT COUNT(_*_) is the best choice.  SELECT COUNT(column) is ***not*** functionally identical.  SELECT COUNT(1) does exactly the same thing but has the disadvantage of being obtuse.

Comment: @EtherDragon what is wrong with COUNT(*)? Also COUNT(SomeIndexedIDColumn) is only predictable if the column is not NULL (since NULL values will be ignored) - the index itself is largely irrelevant unless it is skinnier than the primary key.

Comment: @Aaron, I was looking for a source, and now believe that I sit corrected. Microsoft SQL is optimized for Count(*), so Count(1) offers no performance benefit (nor is it slower). It has been stated in other articles that Oracle runs Count(1) faster.

Comment: That may be true for Oracle. A lot of things are true for one platform and not the other.